# can anybody help to write a lisp code to find the first element which is satisfying the predicate in the list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

can any body help me to write the common lisp code? as following:
create a find first predicate list function to return the first element which is satisfying the condition has been given in the list or nil if no element can be satisfied.

```
(find-first #'oddp '(1 2 3)) returns 1.
(find-first #'characterp '(1 2 3 4 5 6 #\a))
```

Comment: If you have learned how to write a recursive function that iterates a list it that does one of those things already you just have to replace that constant predicate with `(funcall predicate-argument first-element)` and you're done. Good luck!

Comment: Stackoverflow help: 'Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.'

Answer (score 3):

Recursively:

```
(defun find-first (fn ls)
  (cond ((null ls) nil)
        ((funcall fn (car ls)) (car ls))
        (t (find-first fn (cdr ls)))))
```

---

Iteratively using the **loop** macro:

```
(defun find-first (fn ls)
  (loop for item in ls
        if (funcall fn item) 
        return item))
```

---

By mapping:

***mapc*** is explicitly used for its side effects.

```
(defun find-first (fn ls)
  (mapc (lambda (item) 
          (if (funcall fn item) 
              (return-from find-first item))) 
        ls))
```

---

Functionally:

```
(defun find-first (fn ls)
  (car (remove-if-not fn ls)))
```

---

And finally; quite directly. Using the CL standard function **find-if**:

***find-first*** is effectively just an alias of **find-if**.

```
(defun find-first (fn ls)
  (find-if fn ls))
```

Comment: You could also use "some"

Comment: @coredump Not really. `(some #'oddp '(1 2 3 4))` will return `t`. Not `1`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wrote that too quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun find-first (f l)
  (if l
      (if (funcall f (car l))
      (car l)      
      (find-first f (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: This is wrong. If the the list is empty or if it does not contain an element satisfying `f`, the function will cause an error.